# How to solve this infinite loop (do while loop)?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c_row;
    int col;

    do{
        cout << "Enter the starting coordinates: ";
        cin >> c_row >> col;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;
    }
    while(!(toupper(c_row) >='A' && toupper(c_row) <= 'J') ||
           !(col>=1 && col <= 10) );

    cout << "right input !!" << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask the user to input a coordinate on the below graph (a graph with row = A to J, col = 1 to 10). If the user enters the wrong input, the program will ask again until the user enter the right input.

[image: the graph image]

It works when invalid input is like "z11", "A0", "31241".

[image: the output with these input]

But it will cause an infinite loop when the invalid input is like "8z", "uu", "abcde".

[image: the output with these input]

How can I solve this problem, and why does it happen?

Comment: When you do `cin >> c_row >> col;` you have a perfect opportunity to check if the extraction worked by checking if `cin` is still in a good state.
`if(cin >> c_row >> col) {good} else {bad}` ... If `bad`, check if the stream is `eof()`. If so, no use trying to get more input.

Comment: If you want to read a line of text and then parse it, why don't you write code that reads a line of text and then parses it?

Comment: Thanks for reply! This code is a function definition of another code. Because I want to use these two values as two variables for a 2D Array. so I have to get them separate.

Comment: When you read an int with `>>` and you input a non-digit, it puts the stream into an error state and all operations after that are ignored. Clear the error flag with `cin.clear()` and ignore the bad input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the order in which you take the inputs. Row is the `char` variable and column is the `int` variable. In your code, you take the first character as the `char` and second input character as the `int`. So the program works fine until first input character is the row and second input character is the column (Ex:- a5, b2) but if you change the order of the input by providing the column first and row second, then the relevant ASCII character for the provided value for column is stored in the `char` variable `c_row` and the integer representation of the row is stored in `int` variable `col`. So the program goes crazy.

So you have two options. Give the inputs in the correct order, without messing up the order(eg :- a2, b2, c2 etc.). Or you can write the program to store correct values in correct variables before checking whether the input is correct. Second option is described below.

Use to char variables to store the two input values. I used an array of 2 elements in the example.

```
char inputs[2];
cin >> inputs[0] >> inputs[1];
```

Then check which variable has the `char` value and which variable has the digit using `isalpha(char c)` and `isdigit(char c)` methods. One variable should be a digit while other be an alphabetic character. Any other combination is invalid, take the input again by iterating loop again using `continue;`

```
if(isdigit((char)inputs[0]) && isalpha((char)inputs[1])){
    //column is inputs[0] and row is inputs[1]
} 
else if (isalpha((char)inputs[0]) && isdigit((char)inputs[1]))
{
    //column is inputs[1] and row is inputs[0]
} else
{
    //invalid input combination, so iterate again.
    continue;
}
```

Now you have to assign values to the `c_row` and `col` based on the given inputs. But the inputs array is a `char` array so you have to parse the `char` to `int` before assigning to value to `col`. I created a method called `str_to_int(char c)` to do the type conversion / value parsing.

```
int str_to_int(char c) {
    string str = "";
    str += c;
    stringstream ss(str);
    int num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}
```

Using `str_to_int(char c)` method assign `int` value to `col` and assign other value to `c_row`. Do this in the above if statements.

```
if(isdigit((char)inputs[0]) && isalpha((char)inputs[1])){
    col = str_to_int(inputs[0]);
    c_row = inputs[1];
} 
else if (isalpha((char)inputs[0]) && isdigit((char)inputs[1]))
{
    col = str_to_int(inputs[1]);
    c_row = inputs[0];
} else
{
    continue;
}
```

Nice! now the program should work. Complete code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int str_to_int(char c) {
    string str = "";
    str += c;
    stringstream ss(str);
    int num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}



int main()
{
    char c_row;
    char inputs[2];
    int col;

    do{
        cout << "Enter the starting coordinates: ";
        cin >> inputs[0] >> inputs[1];


        if(isdigit((char)inputs[0]) && isalpha((char)inputs[1])){
            col = str_to_int(inputs[0]);
            c_row = inputs[1];
        } 
        else if (isalpha((char)inputs[0]) && isdigit((char)inputs[1]))
        {
            col = str_to_int(inputs[1]);
            c_row = inputs[0];
        } else
        {
            continue;
        }

        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;

    }
    while(!(toupper(c_row) >='A' && toupper(c_row) <= 'J') ||
        !(col>=1 && col <= 10) );

    cout << "right input !!" << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```